# Script to alert when Root Password Expiry in AIX

Tags: shell, aix

I am trying to build a script in AIX which I am planing to run as cron job.
I want the script to check if the root password will expire with in 10 days and trigger an email. I have written a script to trigger mail but I am not sure how to write a script for password expiry for root.

This is script for sending mail .

```
#!/bin/sh
sendmail -t -F 'ABC ' -f 'abc@xyz.com' << test.mail
From: ABC <abc@xyz.com>
To:  def@xyz.com
Subject:
Password expired in 10 days
```

This script works fine .

But i want a script for AIX that will check root password expiry within 10 days of expiry date .

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/brian/entry/don_t_let_your_aix_passwords_expire5?lang=en

Comment: Above script works very nicely for me on my AIX 5.2 box.

Comment: `root         -160      Thu Jun 13 13:41:47 2013  Thu Jun 13 13:41:47 2013  0` - This is what it says for root .

Comment: Great, it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like,

lastupdate=`lssec -f /etc/security/passwd -a lastupdate -s <username> | cut -d " " -f2 |cut -d "=" -f2`

maxage=`lsuser -a maxage itimadm | cut -d " " -f2 |cut -d "=" -f2` 
maxage=$(($maxage*7))

expires=$(($lastupdate+(60*60*24*$maxage)))
expire_date=`perl -le 'print scalar localtime $expires`

daysremaining=ceil((($expires - $now) / (60*60*24)) - 1)

echo $username,$maxage,$expire_date,$daysremaining

Though this is not full fledged script but logic is present (improvement is possible :) ) and you can add if clause for checking condition (daysremaining<10) then call your mailing script which will send mail to respective users.